# What is this icon called (react native vector icon)

Tags: android, react-native, vector, icons

[image]

I found this simple hamburger icon. i want this type of stylish icon. What is the name of this icon

Comment: Yes I am asking what it's called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one solution for your question is [Material Design for developers](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=format_align_justify&style=outline)

also, you can use these [React native all icons](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)

Comment: I found similar icon called 'notes' in metrical icon thanks for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create this Icon by yourself with [Figma](https://www.figma.com)

Comment: What's the another way to use that icon without creating it.